# How can I test an NSString for being nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, null

Can I simply use

```
if(myString == nil)
```

For some reason a string that I know is null, is failing this statement.

Comment: that's how, can't know anything without the rest of your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that my string in the debugger was reporting as (null) but that was due to how it was being assigned, I fixed it and now it is reporting as nil. This fixed my issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

Is it possible that your string is not in fact `nil`, and is instead just an empty string? You could try testing whether `[myString length] == 0`.

Comment: why this is not selected as an answer yet!

Answer (score 16):

You can find [more on objective C string here.](http://i-phone-dev.blogspot.com/2011/11/iphone-nsstring-operations.html)

```
+ (BOOL ) stringIsEmpty:(NSString *) aString {

    if ((NSNull *) aString == [NSNull null]) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (aString == nil) {
        return YES;
    } else if ([aString length] == 0) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        aString = [aString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if ([aString length] == 0) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;  
}

+ (BOOL ) stringIsEmpty:(NSString *) aString shouldCleanWhiteSpace:(BOOL)cleanWhileSpace {

    if ((NSNull *) aString == [NSNull null]) {
        return YES;
    }

    if (aString == nil) {
        return YES;
    } else if ([aString length] == 0) {
        return YES;
    } 

    if (cleanWhileSpace) {
        aString = [aString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if ([aString length] == 0) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;  
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you may check your getting string using this

```
   if(myString==(id) [NSNull null] || [myString length]==0 || [myString isEqualToString:@""])
    {
     //String is null or bad response
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Notice length = 0 doesn't necessary mean it's nil

```
NSString *test1 = @"";
NSString *test2 = nil;
```

They are not the same. Although both the length are 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can implicitly check for `nil` (allocated, but not initialized) with this:

```
if (!myString) { 
    //do something
}
```

If `myString` was assigned from a dictionary or array, you may also wish to check for `NSNULL` like this:

```
if ([myString isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    //do something
}
```

Finally (as Sophie Alpert mentioned), you can check for empty strings (an empty value):

```
if ([myString length] == 0) {
    //do something
}
```

Often, you may want to consolidate the expressions:

```
if (!myString || [myString length] == 0) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem today. Despite assigning a string to be nil: `NSString *str = nil;`, the test `if (str == nil)` returned `FALSE`! Changing the test to `if (!str)` worked, however.

Answer (score 0):

**Check NSAttributedString is empty:**

```
let isEmpty = atrributedString.string.isEmpty
```