# NSMutableAttributedString check nil value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

I created a `NSMutableAttributedString` and I'm appending the value dynamically. I need to check if this string is `nil` or not. I manually assigned `nil` but still the condition below fails. Is there any way to check this?

```
 attribStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
 attribStr = nil;
 if([attribStr isEqualToAttributedString:nil]) { // doesn't execute}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482276/how-can-i-test-an-nsstring-for-being-nil

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're getting started with objective-C :-)

When you send a message to `nil` (which is what you are doing by sending the `isEqualToAttributedString:` message to `attribStr`) it immediately returns `0`. So your condition is always false.

If you want to check if `attribStr` is `nil`, simply do :

```
if (attribStr == nil) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
if (!attribStr) {
    // nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
if([attribStr isEqualToAttributedString:nil])
```

do this

```
if(attribStr){
//means attribStr contains non nil value
}else{
//contains nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vijay change the code to attribStr == nil

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attribStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
attribStr = nil;
if(attribStr == nil)
{
  NSLog(@"The strig is nil");
}
```