# Check for NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, nsstring

I am looking for robust, iron clad code to check if an NSString property has a valid string in it as opposed to being empty, null, nil etc.

The property is:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
```

I have been using the following?

```
if (self.item.name==nil) {
//do something
}
else {
//do something else
}
```

However, not sure this is working right.  (Full logic is far more complicated so not trivial to trace if logic working right every time.)

I have also tried `self.item.length>0`, however, it says length is not a valid property.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**EDIT:**

Item is an instance of an object such as a shirt.  It corresponds to an entity in core data.  name is a property of the object.  I have changed it from text to name to avoid confusion with text as a defined term.

Comment: after checking against `nil` use `self.item.text.length > 0`

Comment: or just skip checking for `nil` and directly check the length. Sending a message to `nil` results in `0` anyway.

Comment: What is `self.item`? You show a property named `text` but nothing named `item`.

Comment: item is an object corresponding to an entity in core data.  text is a property for the object, as in shirt.color.

Comment: length is not a valid property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `self.item` is a UILabel or UITextField. The property that you have defined is named `text`. So you are working with the wrong variable. You can either check `self.item.text.length > 0` or `self.text.length > 0`. Whichever is your actual property.

Comment: I changed the word text to name.   text, now name, does not refer to the .text property of a textfield or label, but rather to a string property of an object.

Comment: So you can use self.item.name.text.length > 0

Comment: I tried it but it will not accept either text or length.  item is a property of an NSObject that corresponds to a core data entity.  Exact error messages are 'Property 'text' not found on object of type 'Items' and Property 'length' not found on object of type Items.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482276/how-can-i-test-an-nsstring-for-being-nil suggests that (item.name==nil) may be adequate

Comment: You shouldn't access text or length. Access name first, then access text then length.

Comment: You are right.  I forgot I had to mention item twice because it's actually reached via a relationship as in self.item.item.nam...Thx!